# Hyper-V host w/SCVMM & Backup Excec

Tags: hyper-v, scvmm, backupexec

I wanted to get any feedback with installing Microsoft System Center Virtual Machine Manager on our Hyper-V host that also has Symantec Backup Exec 2010.

Our host is running as a member of the domain, and has Backup Exec 2010 installed. We would like to add Virtual Machine Manager 2008 to manage our vm's. I know Microsoft recommends that not much of anything be running on the host, but I wanted to see if anyone is running this configuration and any potential problems/issues I should be looking for?

Also, can we use the workgroup edition of SCVMM or do we require the Enterprise edition?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Im running SCVMM workgroup and be2010 on the same machine, although we're not attaching the hyper-v host to the domain. Everything seems to be running great.

Comment: Your Hyper-V host is running SCVMM and BE2010? How many VMs are running on your host?

Comment: Its actually on a clients server. They have 4 VMs total, Exchange, Terminal Services, Accounting APPs, Secondary DC/Misc network apps. Backup is about 200gigs total, small company about 25 users.

Comment: We've got an office in the same situation. Two Hyper-V hosts, approx 20 VMs between the two hosts and BE2010 running on the lower-loaded host. Works well so far.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question about which edition is, "It depends"

One of the only differences between Enterprise and Workgroup, is the amount of hosts you can manage with it. I don't know the number for Enterprise, but Workgroup is only 5 hosts. How many Hyper-V hosts are you going to be managing?

As for installing Backup Exec, also, "It depends"

How powerful is your server? Is it also running the Hyper-V role? Can you dedicate a few additional gigs of memory to just BE 2010? If so, I can't imagine any 'issues' arising, other than bring down performance and resources of the host OS and VMs, if applicable. As always with a VM host, the more you load onto the host OS, the less resources that will be available to your VMs.

Comment: I was worried about performance for the VMs if I were to install SCVMM along side BE2010. THe host server has 32GB RAM and we plan on running 4 VMs....one being a heavily used SQL server...

Comment: The number of VMs doesn't really matter. 10 VMs could use less resources than 2 if they each had a lot of CPU cores and memory assigned to them. Leave plenty of extra memory unassigned to VMs so the parent partition can use it for the local apps at least so they can run successfully.